# Can I open a bank account in the US remotely? Will I pay taxes for the money on it?

Tags: taxes, bank-account

Suppose I get a remote job in US, being Argentinian, and I want them to pay me in a local bank, so I withdraw the money when needed from ATMs in Argentina.

Is it possible? Will I have to pay taxes for this money?

What if I go on vacations to the US with a Tourist/Business Visa that does not allow me to work? Will I be breaching the agreement if I have to take an urgent task while I'm still in the US?

Answer (score 1):

Answering for US tax only: The bank account makes absolutely zero difference.

If you are not a US national and not resident in the US, but earn income from a US employer/client/customer, generally that income is not subject to US tax (no matter where it is banked). However there are (complicated) exceptions, particularly if you are considered to be operating a 'trade or business' in the US or US real estate is involved. Start at https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/nonresident-aliens and proceed through pub 519 if you have time to spend.

I do not know (or answer) about Argentinian taxes.

Whether you can find a US bank that wants to open and maintain an account for a foreigner (which is extra paperwork and regulation for them) is a different Q, that is already asked and answered:

- [Can I open a US bank account even if I don't live in the country?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/5028/can-i-open-a-us-bank-account-even-if-i-dont-live-in-the-country)
- [Opening a bank account in the USA as a foreigner](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/19238/opening-a-bank-account-in-the-usa-as-a-foreigner)

B1/B2 visas do not allow you to work, but that isn't really in scope of money.SX and belongs over on travel.SX (or expatriates.SX for longer stay);  https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25416/work-as-freelancer-while-tourist-in-us-for-an-already-existing-us-client seems to cover it.