# Stimulus check for overseas citizens

Tags: stimulus

We live outside USA and received treasury stimulus checks last Year by mail and still can’t find a way to cash it. Local banks do not want to cash US checks. We don’t have a Bank account in US.
Can anyone suggest what we should do with the check ? Thank you

Comment: Do you have a local branch any of the major banks that have branches across the world (eg. Citibank, etc.)?  Or perhaps a brokerage account that will accept the check as a deposit?

Comment: Make a bank account in the US.

Comment: Read this answer on how to open bank account in USA for US citizens abroad: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/43582/opening-us-bank-account-for-us-citizen-while-abroad

Comment: What do you do when you get a tax refund from the IRS?

Comment: How old is the check? Is it even still valid?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep: I guess it is fairly common for overseas citizens to have 0 US tax liability, if the Foreign Earned Income Exclusion excludes all their income. In that case they would not need to pay taxes to IRS or get refunds from IRS.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps you can endorse the check and give it to a relative or friend who has a US bank account to cash it for you and give you the money.

Comment: That's darned risky.

Comment: This would be considered as a taxable donation/income to the relative from his end. The relative wouldn’t accept to give the check back in full.